# Use LazyVStack in SwiftUI 1

Tags: swiftui, vstack, swiftui-foreach

One of the new features of SwiftUI 2 are [LazyVStacks](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvstack). Is it possible to implement its functionality in the current SwiftUI framework? I have the following code sample where I want to use it:

```
var body : some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading){
        ScrollView {
            Text("sample")
            VStack{ // I want to have a LazyVStack here
                ForEach(1..<10000, id: \.self) {_ in
                    Text("test")
                }       
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Normally i would use a List which is by default lazy. But due to other constraints it's not possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Xcode 12 beta in order to use LazyStacks. If you are coding for an iOS app, the simulator will run correctly, but if you are coding for a macOS app you will have to update to Big Sur also in order to run the SwiftUI 2 code.

Comment: At my present knowledge it not possible neither use LazyVStack nor other workaround. Although you cannot use lists, check this (maybe be useful for you): https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/210/how-to-fix-slow-list-updates-in-swiftui